# Show / hide option of menu depending some conditions

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I want to show / hide an option from menu depending some field from user table. Exist a way to do that ? For example if user.isFirst() then hide option 'Product' from menu.

```
easy_admin:
site_name: '<img src="/build/images/logo.png" alt="dfg" />'
formats:
    datetime: 'Y-m-d'
design:
    brand_color: '#009036'
    color_scheme: 'light'
    form_theme: 'vertical'
    templates:
        layout: 'admin/default/layout.html.twig' #for rewrite layout and add edit my account button

    menu:
    - label: 'menu.labels.dashboard'
      route: 'route_declarant_dashboard'
      icon: 'dashboard'
      default: true
      params:
          menuIndex: 0
    - label: 'menu.labels.products'
      entity: 'Products'
      icon: 'shopping-bag'
    - label: 'menu.labels.users'
      entity: 'Users'
      icon: 'bullhorn'
```

So the idea is :

1. Hide "Products" --> if user.isFirst()
2. Show "Products" --> other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can extends easy admin menu ([doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#overriding-the-default-templates-using-symfony-s-mechanism)) by creating a `menu.html.twig` in the folder `app/templates/easy_admin/`

```
{% extends '@!EasyAdmin/default/menu.html.twig' %}

<!-- [...] extract for example -->
{% if is_granted("CAN_SEE_PRODUCT")) and item.label = 'Products' %} <!-- your if condition of viewing menu link -->
    <a href="{{ path }}" {% if item.target|default(false) %}target="{{ item.target }}"{% endif %}>
            {% if item.icon is not empty %}<i class="fa {{ item.icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
            <span>{{ item.label|trans(domain = translation_domain) }}</span>
            {% if item.children|default([]) is not empty %}<span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>{% endif %}
    </a>
{% endif %}
<!-- [...] extract -->
```

This will only hide the link. The user will still be able to access the other pages unless you change easy admin controller.
You can get some inspiration from this [github pull request discution](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/807) about showing menu according to user roles for easy admin.